# Angular 10 upgrade error with @angular-material-components/datetime-picker

Tags: angular10

I did angular upgrade from 9.1 to 10. All of a sudden @angular-material-components/datetime-picker is causing errors. I've tried to upgrade @angular-material-components/datetime-picker to different pacakages, but none seems working.

The error i'm getting is pasted below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUFZ4.png)

"@angular-material-components/datetime-picker": "^4.0.4",
"@angular/animations": "10.2.5",
"@angular/cdk": "10.2.7",
"@angular/common": "10.2.5",
"@angular/compiler": "10.2.5",
"@angular/core": "10.2.5",
"@angular/flex-layout": "^9.0.0-beta.29",
"@angular/forms": "10.2.5",
"@angular/http": "7.2.16",
"@angular/localize": "^10.2.5",
"@angular/material": "^10.2.7"

Initial version of @angular-material-components/datetime-picker when I was using Angular 9, was 2.0.4. Now I tried updating it to different versions, all gave me same error. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.